# anchor opening and downloading if possible

Tags: php, html, image, targeting

I have a group of links with `href` of an `image` how can i open this in another page within an `<image>` tag ? or an `iframe` and can i get the information shown inside the `iframe`

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($files)) {             
    echo('<tr>
        <td>&diams; <a href="uploads/'.$row['file_name'].'">'.$row['file_name'].'</a> </td>
    </tr>');                
}
```

Comment: I really don't understand your question.

Comment: add `target="_blank"` to your `a` tag

Comment: If you want to use a `img` tag, you have to create another page for your tag. Actually you can directly point to the image source. When user open that source in a new window, it will show while not download it.

Comment: sorry i tink what i meant was can i target the a tag in an image tag ??

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can nest an img tag inside a  tag.

The result will be something like:

```
<a href=''><img src=''/></a>
```